# Mock Spring Component

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock, spring-test, powermockito

I am using Mockito to mock spring beans.

It works fine when I mock an interface.

In our application, there are few @Component beans which do not implement any interface.

When I try to mock such component , the spring context tries to inject the properties inside those components.

Does Mockito not support mocking spring components which do not implement any interface ?

Attached example as requested

```java
public interface EmployeeInterface {
    public Long saveEmployee(Employee employee);
}

@Component
public class EmployeeImpl implements EmployeeInterface {

    @Autowired
    public EmailSender emailSender

    public Long saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        ...
    }
}

public interface EmailSender {
    public boolean sendEmail(Email email);
}

@Component
public class EmailSenderImpl implements EmailSender {

    @Autowired
    MailServerInfo  MailServerInfo;

    public boolean sendEmail(Email email) {
        ...
    }
}

public interface MailServerInfo {
    public String getMailServerDetails();
}

@Component
public class MailServerInfoImpl {

    public String getMailServerDetails() {
        ...
    }
}

@Profile("Security-test")
@Configuration
public class SecurityTestMockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EmailSender emailSender() {
        return Mockito.mock(EmailSender.class);
    }
}

@ActiveProfiles("Security-test")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context-test.xml" })
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface employeeInterface;

    @Test
    public void testSaveEmployee() {
        employeeInterface.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

In the above example if I mock EmailSender using Mockito it works perfectly fine.

In the below scenario, EmailSender is a Spring component which does not implement any interface. In the below case, I get error during auto wiring.

```java
public interface EmployeeInterface {
    public Long saveEmployee(Employee employee);
}

@Component
public class EmployeeImpl implements EmployeeInterface {

    @Autowired
    public EmailSender emailSender

    public Long saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        ...
    }
}

@Component
public class EmailSender {

    @Autowired
    MailServerInfo MailServerInfo;

    public boolean sendEmail(Email email) {
        ...
    }
}

public interface MailServerInfo {
    public String getMailServerDetails();
}

@Component
public class MailServerInfoImpl {

    public String getMailServerDetails() {
        ...
    }
}

@Profile("Security-test")
@Configuration
public class SecurityTestMockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EmailSender emailSender() {
        return Mockito.mock(EmailSender.class);
    }
}

@ActiveProfiles("Security-test")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context-test.xml" })
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface employeeInterface;

    @Test
    public void testSaveEmployee() {
        employeeInterface.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

In the second scenario, the autowiring fails because EmailSender could not find MailServerInfo implementation.

Comment: Please attach your test class

Comment: Attached the test class

Comment: Please provide context-test.xml.

Comment: Why are you using `PowerMockRunner` from PowerMock and `mock` from Mockito? You should stick with one mocking library.

Comment: I have used PowerMockRunner to mock a static class in my test

Comment: test-context has only <context:annotation-config/> and package to scan. Is any other configuration needed for mockito ?

Comment: @RenéScheibe PowerMock is perfectly fine to use with Mockito and is a common practice for mocking static objects.

Answer (score 6):

**Problems**

You are mixing frameworks and annotations quite a bit. Spring uses `@Autowired`. Mockito uses `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. You also use multiple ways to configure your application context in the tests - `@Configuration` and `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { ... })`- which is not working this way. See [Mixing XML, Groovy scripts, and annotated classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-mixed-config) for all the details.

The question is if you want to write a unit test using mocks or if you want to write an integration test using no mocks but a Spring context?

**Unit Tests**

If you want to mock `EmailSender` then use Mockito's `@Mock` annotation. You can then let Mockito inject the dependencies of `EmployeeImpl` via `@InjectMocks`.

```
@Mock
EmailSender emailSender;

@InjectMocks
EmployeeImpl employee;
```

You can also have a look at a tutorial like this https://dzone.com/articles/use-mockito-mock-autowired

**Integration Tests**

If you want to write an integration test use either

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration { ... }

@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class })
public class MyTest { ... }
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:context-test.xml" })
public class MyTest { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. That was useful . I want to write an integration test for a spring context.  There will be nested autowiring of several beans within the application context. By using the ActiveProfile and @primary annotation , I am able to successfully mock such beans within the application context.  In my example , from the junit test class , I access only the EmployeeInterface , which internally has dependencies on other beans . I get error only when I try to mock a Spring Component , which does not implement an interface. Otherwise it works .Hope I have made my scenario clear.

Comment: The ContextConfiguration tag does not work with MockitoJunitRunner.

Answer (score 0):

```
public EmailSender emailSender;
public EmployeeImpl employeeImpl;   
    
@BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        emailSender= Mockito.mock(emailSender.class);
    
        // Manually create an instance and set mocks
       employeeImpl= new EmployeeImpl (emailSender);
    }
```