# Mock @Component bean for Spring boot test context

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test

I need to mock @Component beans for all my tests.

I ve tried to use a @Primary and @TestConfiguration and excludeFilter in the @ComponentScan but it does not work.

How can I put a mock bean into the ApplicationContext instead of my real bean?

Comment: You use a @MockBean

Comment: You would use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations.

This answer has some helpful information on mocking @Component beans and creating junit and integration tests https://stackoverflow.com/a/42170731/15187468

Comment: Thank you, but I need to mock a bean in the ApplicationContext and overwrite this bean for all tests.

Comment: Did you already try the hint in the comment of @Lesiak ? This does the trick and is IMHO the the answer to your question or do you need some more help with an example?