# @Mock not working to mock @Component class in springboot

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to create a Mock instance for spring Component class. Below is the spring component class.

```
@Component
public class MyComponentMapperClass {

@Value("${some.property}")
private String var;

public void someMapperMethod() { // }
```

This is my test class setup where I am trying to mock the above component class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyDAOImpl.class})
public class MyDAOImplTest {

@Mock MyComponentMapperClass myComponentMapperClass;

}
```

While debugging, I see that Intellij highlights a mock object as "Mock Object of XYZClass", but for the mock I created above it doesn't happen like that.
In addition I have tried:

```
MyComponentMapperClass myComponentMapperClass =  Mockito.mock(MyComponentMapperClass.class)
```

but still mock object is not created. This seems to be very straight-forward, but I haven't figured it out yet.

here is an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847174/ren%c3%a9-scheibe [Mock Spring Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049445/mock-spring-component), which suggests to do the same, but is not working for me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use @InjectMocks

Comment: @InjectMocks would create an instance of the class and inject mocks to this instance, but what I need is a mock object.

Comment: Which mock maker are you using?

Comment: I edited the answer. But, I didn't find an import for @Mock from Powermock.

Comment: Please add MyComponentMapperClass to the PrepareForTest and use PowerMockito.mock(MyComponentMapperClass.class) to create a mock. Instead of Mock annotation.